# make header, sidebar & footer constant across website

Tags: php, css, design-patterns, header, footer

I am programming with Php and i need these elements constant through the web page:
header, sidebar & footer (all php files)

all these files define the respective functions like create_header() and so on that generate the html and i have a css that layout these elements (using div id="header",id="sidebar"..)

as for  the pages of actual content all they do is  include this files, make the calls and then generate their respective content, all layout through divs, all their content is  inside the div class="content"

is it good practice to use this for each page or which method should i use?

Comment: i think a common practice is to create a file called "namespace.php" and stick all of your commonly used includes in that, then you only need to include 1 file in each page

Comment: that makes things a easier, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use for my applications. See if this helps:

site_config.php:

```
<?php

define('DIR_BASE', dirname( dirname(__FILE__) ));
define('DIR_CLASSES', DIR_BASE . '/classes/');

// this is specific to the site
define('DIR_SITE', DIR_BASE . '/yoursite/');
define('SITE_NAME', 'yoursite');

// these would be specific to this site only
define('DIR_SITE_VIEWS', DIR_SITE . 'views/' );
define('DIR_SITE_COMPONENTS', DIR_SITE . 'components/');

define('BASE_URL', 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('SITE_URL', BASE_URL . '/yoursite');

// static content for the site
define('DIR_STATIC', SITE_URL . '/static');
define('DIR_JS', DIR_STATIC . '/js');
define('DIR_CSS', DIR_STATIC . '/css');
define('DIR_SITE_IMG', SITE_URL . '/images');
?>
```

This is what my template looks like:

```
<?php
// site_template.php
// template for adding a new page directly under main directory of this site
require_once('site_config.php');

$pgtitle = "Title of the Page";
include_once(DIR_SITE_VIEWS . 'site_header_begin.php');

// custom css/javascript goes here
include_once(DIR_SITE_VIEWS . 'site_header_end.php');
?>
<?php
// main content of the page goes here
?>
<?php
include_once(DIR_SITE_VIEWS . 'site_footer.php');
?>
```

site_header_begin.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>
    <?php if (isset($pgtitle) && ($pgtitle != '')){echo $pgtitle." :: ";}?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="AUTHOR" content="" />
    <meta name="KEYWORDS" content="" />
    <meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="" />

    <!-- common css goes here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.17/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

site_header_end.php:

```
</head><!-- end the header here -->
<body ><!-- start the body here -->
```

site_footer.php:

```
        <div id="footer"><a name="pageFooter"></a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will make header/footer "constant" and dynamic and everything will be defined in terms of constants defined in the site_config.php file. You just need to add appropriate views, static, classes and components directories. See if this helps.

Comment: THanks for answering but i don'get define('DIR_STATIC', SITE_URL . '/static');, why /static, and also DIR_SITE can be wwww.mysite.com right?

Comment: you don't have to put them there if you don't need to. They are specific to my site since I store all js/css/img files in a static directory.

Comment: also DIR_SITE will allow you to include/require files without needing the absolute path for them. This code is server independent. You only need to make changes to site_config.php file. You might need to customize it a bit to your need.

Comment: Alright, many thanks now i known a good approach to structure my website.

Comment: sure. Understand that this is one of many possible approaches. You can start with this and then customize it to your need.

Answer (score 1):

This is the system that I use when programming with PHP, and it works well for me. It's a good way to ensure consistency, provided that you remember to add the includes to all pages. It also makes updating the layout of the website easier. It's a shame there is no Template or Master Page in PHP, which would be more robust. However, I would strongly recommend HTML's new semantic tags, including `<header>`, `<footer>` and `<sidebar>` instead of giving id's to appropriate `<div>`'s.

Comment: that's good, but many of my potencial users still use IE 8 which not support those specialized tags

Answer (score 0):

`include` function in PHP is a good way to make the website template constant
header and left pane.

`in1.php (this file contains top part of the constant interface)`

```
<?php
//session maintenance code:
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin interface</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/pageBody.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dropdown.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <!--top divisor-->
     <div id="topp">
        <center>
            top pane content should be coded here
        </center>
    </div>
    <!--end of the top divisor-->

    < div id="bottom">
         <!--start of the left pane-->
         <div id="leftd" >
            <P>
                 left pane content should be coded here:
            </P>
        </div>
```

Then the foot(bottom) part

`in2.php (this file contains the constant end part of the web site)`

```
    <!--start of the footer-->
    <div id="foot" style="">
        <center class="footfix">
            &copy;KS <a href="http://ugvle.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk">visit us</a>
        </center>
    </div>
    <!--end of the footer-->

    <div></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Finally we can define the dynamic parts of the web site. I have demonstrated a login window.

`login.php`

```
<?php 
include 'in1.php'; //previously made top part
?>
        <!--start of the dynamic main pane-->
        <div id="rightd" >
            <form name="login" action="user.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr><td>Email: </td><td colspan="2" ><input type="text" name="email" size="30" required/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>password: </td><td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="pass" size="30" required/></td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="OK" name="log"/><input type="reset" value="clear" /></td></tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <?php
                //a php code here:
            ?>

        </div>
        <!--end of the dynamic main pane-->
<?php 
include 'in2.php'; //previously made footer part
?>
```