# get the main site folder path in php

Tags: php

In PHP how can I get the site folder path anywhere in the site?

> ex: /var/www/sitename

this is what I got so far:

```
$r1 = $_SERVER['document_root']          //  = /var/www
$r2 = __DIR__                           //  = /var/www/sitename/view/folder/subf
$r3 = str_replace($r1 . '/', '', $r2);  //  = sitename/views/folder/subf
$arr = explode('/', $r3);               //  = array (sitename, views, folder ...)
$sitepath = $r1 . '/' . $arr[0]         //  = /var/www/sitename
```

Is there any other easiest way?.

EDIT: there are many site copies in different servers with different names, could be site1 (/var/www/site1) or sitexx347(/var/www/sitexx347) or onemoresite.com (public_html/onemoresite), and I want to know it anywhere in the website so instead of calling

```
require_once '../../../../../../config.php';
```

or

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/IveNoIdeaWhatTheNameIs/config.php';
```

I can do this:

```
require_once $sitepath . 'config.php';
```

I repeat, I have no idea what the site name is.

EDIT 2: the way I do it now works perfect, I was just trying to know an easiest way. 
Actually this can be shorten to do it like this:

```
$r = explode('/', str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/', '', __DIR__));
$sitepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $r[0];
```

Comment: see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814932/make-header-sidebar-footer-constant-across-website/17815087#17815087 see if the site_config.php code helps.

Comment: Define what you mean by "site folder path"?

Comment: @Maximus2012 : Actually this is one of the things that I want to do with this, no matter where you are in the site you can call require_once($sitepath . '/site_config.php');

Comment: but for the config file to work, won't you have to define $sitepath somewhere ? In my case I am defining equivalent of $sitepath in the config file itself.

Comment: Oh c`mon, it is Very clear in the question, that is exactly what i am asking

Comment: I think my approach is a bit different than yours. Please take a look at the Shredder's answer below. That might be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well The thing is to get the site folder name no matter where is located the script, no matter what is the name of the site, no matter where is located the project (localhost or online), I googled it and I found nothing.It seems that there isn`t a super easy way to do it.

So This is my answer for this

```
$r = explode('/', str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/', '', __DIR__));
$sitepath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . $r[0];
```

The first line returns an array with the path of the script where this code is located  separated by " / " without the document root (public_html or /wamp/www or /var/www) 
The second line concatenates the document_root with the first array element which is the site FOLDER name (Not the host name -- that is not what we want in this case)

So, you can get this to work anywhere inside the website,

> ex1 (linux local)  : in  site1/controller/controller.php you`ll get /var/www/site1
>
> ex2 (server online): in  sitename/views/index.php  you'll get /public_html/sitename
>
>                    ** The hostname could be differentname.com and it does not change.
>
> ex3 (Windows / wamp) in site2/classes/other/sub.php you`ll get C:/wamp/www/site2

Answer (score 3):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should do the trick. As said in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> The document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

You must not have `/var/www/sitename` configured as the root directory.

Edit: There are a couple different ways you go about it, but I think what you have is fine. Be sure you are getting the first element from `explode()` in your shortened version.

Comment: In your case, when you browse your website, you would have to do www.yoursite.com/sitename - is that what you want?

Comment: I want to know the relative path of the main site folder no matter how "DEEP" in the site is located the php script

Comment: From your question, it doesn't sound like you want the relative path. Seems like you want the absolute path.

Comment: sorry, you are right, I edited the question, please take a look

Comment: Oh, I see. You are going to have to do something like what you are doing now then. There are a couple different ways you go about it, but I think what you have is fine. Be sure you are getting the first element from `explode()` in your shortened version.

Answer (score 0):

Put some php file where you want it and get $name = dirname(FILE);

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php